# Blender renders different from preview

Tags: rendering, hair

I have this wierd issue in blender 2.8,

im trying to render (with both cycles and eevee) this wolf

[image: preview]

but when i try to render it does this.

[image: render]

I tried everything and i dont know what to do.
I dont have subdivision surface modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Check your visibility options on each mesh supposed to be rendered. The render visibility toggle is hidden by default in the outliner, find it in the Filters:

[image]

For the main mesh, t looks like you unchecked the "Show Emitter" option in the render panel of your hair settings.

[image]

If neither of these is the issue, maybe check your materials.